# React. Выгрузка объявлений по 10 штук

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

Есть компонента, отображающая объявления, загруженные с сервера. Они должны загружаться по 10 штук.

```
   const Adverts = () => {
      const [adverts, setAdverts] = useState([]);
    
      const getAdverts = async (e) => {
        const code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/adverts");
            console.log(res.data);
            setAdverts(res.data);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", getAdverts);
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("keydown", getAdverts);
        };
      });
    
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
          {adverts.map((item) => (
            <Advert item={item} key={item.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Adverts;
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на F7 загружались следующие 10 объявлений и так далее, пока они не закончатся? Возвращение к предыдущим загруженным объявлениям не предусмотрено.

Comment: а ваш код не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать условие на проверку кода 137(F7). Также нужно вам изменить код, если нужно, чтобы он работал под ваше api. Я не знаю его интерфейс, но предполагаю, что он реализован вот так.
Также не рекомендовал бы делать что-либо при нажатии на кнопку F7, т.к. эта кнопка и так используется браузером (как минимум в Chrome)

```
const Adverts = () => {
  const [adverts, setAdverts] = useState([]);
  const [advertsPage, setAdvertsPage] = useState(1);
  const getAdverts = async (e) => {
    const code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 137) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/adverts",{
                params: {
                    page: advertsPage,
                    count: 10
                    }
                });
        console.log(res.data);
        setAdverts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } finally {
        setAdvertsPage(advertsPage + 1)
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", getAdverts);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", getAdverts);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      {adverts.map((item) => (
        <Advert item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Adverts;
```